# MonetDB -R connector installation

Tags: monetdb

I have started using MonetDB and R.I am trying to install it's connector.But unfortunately the machine where I have installed these two doesn’t have internet accessibility so the mirrors are not accessible. can someone tell me some other way to install it, maybe some connector exe if provided.

Comment: hi, `MonetDBLite` (on CRAN) now replaces `MonetDB.R` and runs embedded (like `RSQLite`).  for more detail, see https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

You can download the binary packages for Windows from CRAN, for example, for R 3.2.x you can download

- https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/MonetDB.R_1.0.0.zip ,
- https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/DBI_0.3.1.zip and
- https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/digest_0.6.9.zip

Then, you can install those using the "Packages" - "Install packages from local zip files" menu entry in the following order: digest, DBI, MonetDB.R .